# How to add DateTimePicker value to Current Time

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datetimepicker

I'm having a difficult time with this. The program is an Alarm clock that takes a user input duration of time and adds the current time to get a label of the future time of when the alarm is finished.

[image: Visual of the alarm here]

I have accomplished removing hardcoded hours but I can't add the current time to the duration

```
Option Strict On
Public Class AlarmTimerFRM
    Private setTime As Date

    Private Sub AlarmTimerFRM_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        outCurrentTimeLBL.Text = Date.Now.ToLongTimeString
        outCurrentTimeLBL.BackColor = Color.LightGray
        Timer1.Start()
        setTimerDTP.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
        setTimerDTP.CustomFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        outCurrentTimeLBL.Text = TimeOfDay.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt")

    End Sub
    Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
        outCurrentTimeLBL.Text = TimeOfDay.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt")

    End Sub

    Private Sub SetBTN_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SetBTN.Click
        REM sets the alarm time 
        Dim OneHourAgo As DateTime
        Dim FormattedTime As String

        OneHourAgo = Now.AddHours(-1)
        FormattedTime = OneHourAgo.ToString("HH:mm:ss")

        AlarmTimeLBL.Text = (FormattedTime)

    End Sub

    Private Sub setTimerDTP_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles setTimerDTP.ValueChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub ResetBTN_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ResetBTN.Click
        REM Resets the alarm time LBL
        AlarmTimeLBL.Text = ""
    End Sub

    Private Sub AlarmTimeLBL_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AlarmTimeLBL.Click

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "setTime" variable should be a `DateTime` so that it includes the date. This makes it easier to deal with current times and durations that span midnight.

Here's what it would like:

```
Private setTime As DateTime

Private Sub AlarmTimerFRM_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    UpdateCurrentTime()
    outCurrentTimeLBL.BackColor = Color.LightGray
    Timer1.Start()
    setTimerDTP.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
    setTimerDTP.CustomFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    UpdateCurrentTime()
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateCurrentTime()
    outCurrentTimeLBL.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt")
End Sub

Private Sub SetBTN_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SetBTN.Click
    setTime = DateTime.Now.Add(setTimerDTP.Value.TimeOfDay)
    AlarmTimeLBL.Text = setTime.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt")
    SetBTN.Enabled = False
    setTimerDTP.Enabled = False
    Timer2.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
    If DateTime.Now >= setTime Then
        Timer2.Stop()
        MessageBox.Show("Alarm time reached!")
        SetBTN.Enabled = True
        setTimerDTP.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This assumes the Timer2 Interval is set to something reasonable like 1000 (one second). Then it is checking every second if the "alarm time" has been reached.

Answer (score 0):

You could plus DateTime.Now with User Input Time.

```
 Dim UserTime As String()
 UserTime = Duration.Text.Split(':')
 AlarmTimeLBL.Text = DateTime.Now.AddHours(UserTime(0)).AddMinutes(UserTime(1)).AddSeconds(UserTime(2))
```